# Internal Hard Drive Recovery - Read Errors (Data Rescue DD)

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive-recovery

I tried to boot up a relatively old computer and it would always blue screen at the Windows XP splash loading part.  I thought something could just be wrong with the board because it was old so I swapped out the drive into a much newer board with better wires.  Same issue.  All the Hirens boot disc utilities I used to try to read the drive treated it as if it was unformatted.  I was able to run a [Data Rescue DD](http://www.datarescue.com/photorescue/v3/drdd.htm) on it completely though, despite consistent read errors throughout the entire drive.  So now I have a ~186GB .dd file on an external drive of mine, and I have no idea how to salvage anything from it.  I am hopeful, but I can't seem to find anything online about these types of files.

I am preparing to try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) on this file shortly (making a backup first!).  I'll let you know how it turns out.

Any suggestions on how to recover any data from this drive would be greatly appreciated!  It is not mission-critical, and I have no intentions of spending money to pay some expert to analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a raw disk image file - a file based representation of the entire hard drive.

It can be mounted easily under Linux, but for Windows you need special software.

A bit of hunting lead me to this software: [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk)

It allows you to mount the image as a virtual drive in Windows and access it as if it were a real hard drive.

I have never used it, so can't vouch for it, but it looks like it should work.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the quick tip!  Going to try that now...

Comment: It worked!  I was able to copy some files off the mounted drive.  No signs of corruption yet, but I'm sure I'll have a few files that will be incomplete.  Thanks!